# Async socket server long operating task

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

my question might be ridiculous, but i couldn't find any info online.

My server constantly reads data sent from clients connected to it, based on the data received, i perform a certain operations.

My question is, if my operation is long, do i need to create a new thread so BeginRecieve won't be blocked? if no, what do i need to do?

code:

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Socket current = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int received;
        try
        {
            received = current.EndReceive(ar);
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
        var st = Helper.ByteToObject(recBuf);
        if ((st is string s))
        {
            if (s == "Something")
            {
                //Long operating task, do i need to use a new thread?
            }
        }
        current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle long running tasks is to have a thread that you start and hand in the task information to. This will allow your main thread to keep receiving data from the clients, while the other thread keeps working on the actual work you need to do.

The way I usually implement this is to define a function for each unique task which takes the requisite input, to be started by the main task when needed. Then I keep a vector to hold all the thread handles so we can track the threads.

You will need a way to synchronize the results of the tasks being operated on by the threads, which could end up creating a race condition, so you will need to add mutexes to prevent issues with that. You may also want to create a processing queue that gets populated by the messages sent from the clients since you don’t want to end up with thousands of threads.

I usually set a thread limit equal to the hardware threads on the system it is running on, and when I need threads I spin up only that many. The queue will allow unprocessed data to wait for a thread to finish its task and become available.

There are many ways to do this, and there are no real correct answers

Comment: Not particularly. If you don’t use threads the long running tasks will block the receives from happening which can lead to some issues. It is actually a good idea to get used to working with threading as it is becoming a lot more prevalent in software being created today.

Comment: Thank you, i don't understand why i don't like using threads, but ill get used to it, considering the fact that this project is not meant for insane scalability, i will keep it simple.

Comment: Once you get used to threads and mutexes they are actually really easy to work with. Just keep at it and you will figure it out :)